# How to have more than one page for your posts if you have 8 posts but can store max 4 on a page

Tags: posts, categories

Hello I am new to wordpress and I am creating a custom template. I am sorry if this is simple and has been asked before.
I have 8 posts in a page and I have set the page to display a maximum of 4 posts on this page. So my question is how can I create something like arrows which can change from "pageName/1" to "pageName/2" which will display the other 4 posts also known as older posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you are looking for is [Pagination](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination).

Placing this code inside the loop should work:

```
<div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?></div>
<div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>
```